# How to abort request Puppeteer when using "Network. requestIntercepted" (same as request.abort () of setRequestInterception)?

Tags: puppeteer, interception

I can't intercept with the `setRequestInterception` function, some important request doesn't go through it.

Instead I used the `Network.setRequestInterception`, and it was nice in addition to not being able to abort the unwanted request.

If I intentionally ignore it with the if else sentence, a lot of request will not leave the browser and cause many errors in the suspended state.

I need an alternate command `request.abort()` when I work with `Network.requestIntercepted`, here is my code:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.enable');
await client.send('Network.setRequestInterception',{
patterns:[
{urlPattern :'*'}
]
});
client.on('Network.requestIntercepted',async({interceptionId,request})=>{
if (request.url.indexOf('Loading') == -1 ){
await client.send('Network.continueInterceptedRequest',{
interceptionId
});
}else{
//I want request.abort()
}
});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the same [`'Network.continueInterceptedRequest'`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-continueInterceptedRequest) can be used to abort:

```js
}else{
  await client.send('Network.continueInterceptedRequest', {
    interceptionId,
    errorReason: 'Aborted',
  });
}
```